# Error while converting word to PDF in vs2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, dll

when i upload msword in server  to convert from word to PDF i am getting error "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 8000401a." and word is not converted to PDF.not all time but i wil get sometime.can you please tel me how to solve. it is not the problem of permission i have given permission in DCOM setting and kept as interactive user. thankyou in advance